# How to take SQL Server databases backup using .bat script file with time stamp

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I am using SQL Server Express edition, so there is no features for backup plan, I want to take databases backup using bat script, and create a scheduler to be run everyday. I have created .bat file but need to place a time stamp at the end of backup file like test_13_April_2017.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
SqlCmd -S SERVER02 -Q "Backup Database testdb To Disk='C:\backup\testdb.bak'"
```

Is there is any way to give time stamp at the end of every DB backup.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend you look at some of the freely available backup code. Here are two possible options I would recommend, as both work on SQL Server Express Edition.

1) [Ola Hallengren's backup code](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).

You can install Ola's code in a database on your server (ex, in a "DBA" utility database), and then backing up the databases will be done by executing a stored procedure. The stored procedure takes care of putting date/time stamps in the file name, and can also take care of cleaning up old backups (and more).

Then, you can use a PowerShell (or cmd file) to call Invoke-SqlCmd (or sqlcmd) to simply call the procedure with the proper parameters.

PowerShell:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance SERVER02 -Database DBA -Query "EXEC dbo.BackupDatabase @Databases='testdb'"
```

cmd:

```
SqlCmd -S SERVER02 -Q "EXEC DBA.dbo.BackupDatabase @Databases='testdb'"
```

2) [The Dbatools PowerShell Module](https://dbatools.io/)

This module includes a simple [Backup-DbaDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/backup-dbadatabase/) command that will perform the backup and include the date/time stamp in the file name. This has fewer bells & whistles than Ola's procedure, but if you don't need the bells & whistles, this simple solution might be just what you need.

```
Backup-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance SERVER02 -Databases testdb -Type Full -BackupDirectory \server2\backups
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%mm%%dd%%yyyy%
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
SqlCmd -S SERVER02 -Q "Backup Database testdb To Disk='C:\backup\testdb"%date%".bak'"
```

[Variables in CMD](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-2-variables.html)

[DateTime in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Side note, you should check out [Ola](https://ola.hallengren.com/) or [Minion](http://minionware.net/) to see if they can make your backup needs more simple.

You can run jobs and things on Express, you don't get the GUI to do it though. Also, maybe there's a circumstance where you can use SQL 2016 Dev instead as that's similar to enterprise but free for development instances only?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make the backup location a variable and load that up with the current datetime.

```
Sqlcmd -S SERVER02 -Q "DECLARE @BackupLocation NVARCHAR(2000) = 'C:\Backup\testdb ' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120) + '.bak', ':', ''); BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK = @BackupLocation;"
```

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell solution looks more compact and clearer than the batch file. Here is a simple command that, can be executed via the PowerShell console, will perform a backup to a file with a current timestamp.

```
SqlCmd -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO DISK='C:\temp\$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").bak'"
```

However, PowerShell has a [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sqlserver-ps) for working with SQL Server which can be installed via the following command:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
```

Then to perform a backup the following command can be used:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "." -Database "MyDB" -BackupFile c:\temp\$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").bak
```

Such a command is more descriptive, and does not contain nested quotes :-)

This script can be run from a regular Windows Command Line or a batch script, for this use `powershell -Command` :

```
powershell -Command Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "." -Database "MyDB" -BackupFile c:\temp\$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").bak
```

For automation, it's better (and easier) to use a PowerShell script instead of batch.

[More examples](https://sqlbak.com/blog/complete-guide-to-sql-server-backup-and-restore-using-the-command-line) on PowerShell and batch.

Learn more about the [backup-database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) and [restore-database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/restore-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) command.